# How to get attribute of xml data without child in php

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to getting attributes of product(despecid) node using php function using [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) and [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) of following xml.

```
<productlist brand="HP" model="Color Laserjet 3000">
   <product despecid="CAN21679">IR C1021/MF8450 Fuser Unit (Fixing Assembly)</product>
   <product despecid="HPRM1-2743-180CN">CLJ 3000/3600/3800 CP3505 fuser unit</product>
   <product despecid="XER003R99755">Xerox XRC toner Q7560A black</product>  
</productlist>
```

but i got out of both ( [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) and [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php))  method output as below.

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#179 (2) {
["@attributes"]=>
 array(2) {
  ["Brand"]=>
    string(2) "HP"
  ["Model"]=>
    string(19) "Color Laserjet 3000"
 }
 ["Product"]=>
   array(6) {
    [0]=>
     string(44) "IR C1021/MF8450 Fuser Unit (Fixing Assembly)"
    [1]=>
     string(36) "CLJ 3000/3600/3800 CP3505 fuser unit"
    [2]=>
      string(28) "Xerox XRC toner Q7560A black"
    [3]=>
      string(27) "Xerox XRC toner Q7561A cyan"
    [4]=>
     string(29) "Xerox XRC toner Q7562A yellow"
    [5]=>
     string(30) "Xerox XRC toner Q7563A magenta"
   }
}
```

Is there any method to get attribute despecid of product. Please help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$xml = <<<XML
<productlist brand="HP" model="Color Laserjet 3000">
   <product despecid="CAN21679">IR C1021/MF8450 Fuser Unit (Fixing Assembly)</product>
   <product despecid="HPRM1-2743-180CN">CLJ 3000/3600/3800 CP3505 fuser unit</product>
   <product despecid="XER003R99755">Xerox XRC toner Q7560A black</product>  
</productlist>
XML;


foreach (simplexml_load_string($xml)->product as $product) {
   print_r($product->attributes()->despecid); 
}
```

See [Demo](http://implode.io/enT48G)